# Is it permissible to use "dum" with the pluperfect subjunctive?

Tags: grammar-identification

Is it ever permissible to use *dum* with the pluperfect subjunctive?

Here is an example of this construction from [Victor of Vita's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Vitensis) [*Historia persecutionis Africanae provinciae*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Historia_persecutionis_Africae_provinciae):

> qui lapides dum cecidissent in terram, plus accendebantur.

For which the translation I'm reading has:

> When these stones had fallen onto the ground, they were kindled further.

Victor of Vita is known for using the pluperfect instead of the imperfect subjunctive in places, but I don't know if this is an example.

**Does *dum* always take the present/imperfect subjunctive?** I'm also wondering if this is just *dum* being confused with *cum*.

Comment: Are you asking about *dum* or *cum*?

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Funnily enough, I think that was just a typo on their part. I linked the source, which does have "dum cecidissent."

Comment: Then this is a good question. I believe in classical Latin this is generally avoided...

Comment: Woodcock (#218-#224) says that when *dum* means "as long as" the use of pluperfect and future perfect are ruled out by the sense. When *dum* means "during the time that" or "until" it can take the pluperfect in certain situations, but I'm not sure that those situations apply in your text. He goes on to say that from the time of Livy and later, the subjunctive pluperfect becomes common to refer to repeated action.